# Delete all Stock Alarm clock alarms in Android

Tags: android, clock, alarm

Is there a way to delete all stock alarm clock alarms in Android?
I am not talking about `alarmservice` intent, I am talking about the actual alarm clock. (Frustratingly both have the same name)

Here is the code I used to set the alarm :

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);

int hour = 6;
int min = 0 ;
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, min);
```

So, is there a way to remove/delete the alarm, through code?

(PS, I'd really appreciate suggestions as to how to improve my questions, rather than receiving a downvote for no reason at all. I'm finding it really hard to understand the Stackoverflow community, no offence)

Comment: I think there are two reasons you didn't get an answer from the community here. One is that deleting other apps on the phone is an inherently kind of suspicious task. The other is that you ask about deleting the stock alarm clock, which is an app, and then post code for creating an alarm through the stock alarm clock app, and then ask how to delete that specific alarm.

If you want to manage alarms, as in create, display and delete, I recommend ignoring the stock alarm clock app and using the `AlarmManager` class.

Comment: Short version: It's not clear what you want to do, and it sounds like you're asking for advice on how to do something potentially malicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I figured out there is no way to do so with one click of a button. (Android security issues). However, there is one way- open the AppInfo page for the Stock Alarm clock on every phone. This is the code I used:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(i);
```

Where package name is the package name of the default clock apps.
Here is a list that I could find online:

```
  String clockImpls[] = {
                    "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "com.google.android.deskclock",
                    "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS",
                    "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl",
                    "com.sonyericsson.organizer.Organizer_WorldClock",
                    "com.htc.android.worldclock.AlarmAlert",
                    "com.htc.android.worldclock.TimerAlert",
                    "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage",
                    "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock",
                    "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE",
                    "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE",
                    "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock",
                    "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock",
                    "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmAlert",
                    "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock",
                    "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmTimerAlert",
                    "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock",
                    "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock",
                    "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.alarm.AlarmAlert",
                    "com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage",
                    "com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "com.htc.android.worldclock.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "com.sonyericsson.alarm.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "zte.com.cn.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "com.mobitobi.android.gentlealarm.ALARM_INFO",
                    "com.urbandroid.sleep.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT",
                    "com.splunchy.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT"
            };
```

PS:
Sadly, I haven't yet figured out a way to get questions answered from the community at StackOverflow. I'd really love people to help me out, in pointing where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Relax. It depends on luck, question quality, difficulty, and time. They help you for FREE, so we can't guess when they'll have the chance to respond. Try to use bounty if you want. FYI, 30%~ of my questions are not answered. Not taken personally.